# Open a modal from a link in wiki-site: Sharepoint removes javascript

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript, modal-dialog

so I tried to add a little horizontal menu to a wiki-site and wanted one of the links to open in a modal Dialog (a contact form). Every time I try to add it about the UI, sharepoint removes the link. Same in SP Designer.

Here's the syntax I'm using:

```
<a onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('url/contactform.aspx');">Contact Form</a>
```

I don't have a clue why it's not working, it's the same syntax I'm using for one of my webpart-buttons and it works like a charm there, would be great to have some ideas on this :)

update: I tried it with `href` attribute, too. same behaviour, sp removes the attribute :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Wiki pages SharePoint will always remove scripts, or calls to javascript. One way to overcome is to use jQuery :live functions in a function in a separate .js file stored somewhere in a Document library and added in page via a CEWP, but then add an ID to your Link item.

Yes, it sounds like overkill, but that would be one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, SharePoint checks the validity of the link and removes it. It doesn't check the validity in custom webparts. You could try to repclace `onclick` with `href` attribute. Hope it helps. Say if it doesn't.

```
<a href="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('url/contactform.aspx');">
Contact Form</a>
```

Comment: sry, will update my question. I tried that, too. Same behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

The first hint from Anatoly was the key for me. Sadly it took 3 hours to find out.

Just insert a new Content editor webpart and insert the code their. When you change the appearance and hide the frame it looks like it is directly inserted on the wiki site.