# Mulitiple Modified by

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath

I'm not sure how to go about this but I am trying to make a column to store modified time and user. Something like:

```
ID        Title        Multiple Reviewers
321       Dog House    John Appleseed on Dec 31 2012
                       Steve Ballmer on Jan 12 2012
                       John Appleseed on Jan 31 2012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options here.

1. You can turn on Version History for this list. I won't show it like you have above, but it will collect the data.
2. You can create a new multiple lines column and append the new modified information to that column.

Comment: I was thinking about the multi-line approach but not sure how to implement. Workflow? Infopath rule?

Comment: How and where is the data being collected / modified? Is it being done in an infopath form? Application Page? Webpart?

Comment: Ideally in the infopath form on the website. I was able to make a workflow to do this as you suggested. is there any way to get the name to be a hyperlink?

Comment: Found this...it might be of additional help.

http://www.sharepointmaestra.com/Blog/Post/4/InfoPath---Appending-Text-in-Multiline-Field-with-Line-Feed

Comment: You can add hyperlinks to multi line text columns that are marked as "Rich text" or "Enhanced rich text"

Comment: How would I hyperlink the name? Currently my string is:

    [%current item:field1%]<br/>
    [%current item:Modified By%] on [%current item:Modified%]

Comment: You can add it in the Insert Formula.

Example: concat('http://mysite?Query=',[%current item:field1%])

http://mesiag.blogspot.com/2011/02/insert-dynamically-changing-hyperlink.html

Comment: Ok so I just put the following into the string builder and it made a link, however it seems dead as nothing happens when I click it.
'<a href="mysite?Query=[%Current Item:Modified By%]>[%Current Item:Modified By%]</a>'

Comment: What do you see when you mouse-over the link?

Comment: The text underlines and the mouse turns into the pointer hand however no url is previewed like you would see on a typical link hover.

Comment: What do you see in the column when you go to Edit Properties for this item?

Comment: When I edit the item than select the link and click "Link Tools" the URL, Description, and Bookmark fields are empty

Comment: Ok I made this work referencing an item in another list which is a partial win. However the link changes the page to the item instead of opening a modal window to display the item.

<a href="https://Internal-SharePoint/sites/Site-In-Refference/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={______}&ID=[%Current Item:ID of Related List%]&ContentTypeID=0x0100EE8D78AC4D1BC84ABF56810B235ACCEA">[%Current Item:Title of Related List%]</a>'

Comment: Try the ShowPopupDialog

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411722%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Not sure if I implemented it incorrectly but I tried that earlier after finding a [similar suggestion](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/59237/38758). I just tried it again with no luck. SP strips the link and I'm left with Text and a dead hyperlink.